# Can not find the project? Redirects to the next route

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a project that can be accessed at the URL:

`myapp.com/project/my-project`

### Route

To be able to use this route, I recorded the following in my Global.asax

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Project", // Route name
    "Project/{url}/{action}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Project", action = "Details" } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

### Action

When you browse the URL ´myapp.com/project/create´, I would like to ´create´ action is called, not my ´details´ action.

But the URL `myapp.com/project/my-project` should usually be interpreted by the `details` action.

```
public ActionResult Details(string projectUrl)
{
    var project = _projectService.Get(projectUrl);

    if (project == null)
        //Not found! Redirect to next route!

    var model = Mapper.Map<ProjectViewModel>(project);

    return View(model);
}
```

### Question

How to make, `Create`, `Delete`, `Edit` to be interpreted by the default route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the create route with your existing route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ProjectCreate", // Route name
    "project/create", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Project", action = "Create" } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Project", // Route name
    "project/{url}/{action}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Project", action = "Details" } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Your project url parameter name should be `url` not `projectUrl` as that is the name of the route value.

Here is my `ProjectController`:

```
public ActionResult Details(string url)
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}
```

The appropriate action is hit when I go to either of these URLs:

- /project/create
- /project/test
- /project/test/details

And pass "test" as the url value.

Its worth noting that routes are **processed in the order they are added**, so you need to make sure they go in order from **most specific to most general** like you have, and not reverse that.

Comment: Before? There would then be the default route? **Thereby:**


`routes.MapRoute(
 "Default", // Route name
 "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
 new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
 "Project", // Route name
 "Project/{url}", // URL with parameters
 new { controller = "Project", action = "Details" } // Parameter defaults
);`

Comment: Anyway, either before or after work.
When I put the route `ProjectDefault` after the default route, the url `myapp.com/project/create`
works perfectly, but `myapp.com/project/my-app` does not work.
**The result is 404.**

Comment: Another detail, how

`/project/{project-url}/edit`  -> call the edit action?

Comment: @RidermandeSousaBarbosa I updated my answer, I misread how you wanted the create route to look, see the answer now.

Comment: That is correct. It worked perfectly! I understand that the routes are processed in the order they are added, so I thought that this code should work. But does not work.    
**Why not work?**
`routes.MapRoute(
 "Default", // Route name
 "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
 new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
 "Project", // Route name
 "Project/{url}/{action}", // URL with parameters
 new { action = "Details" } // Parameter defaults
);`

Comment: The order is deliberate, so `myapp.com/project/test` should fall on the route `project` 

About the parameter `projectUrl` in the action I've noticed and have corrected!

Comment: Because the format matches the pattern of the first route (since its a more general route).  You could have it work in this order by using route constraints where you tell the "Default" route that a controller value of "project" is not valid for this rule.  But by reversing the order you avoid the need for the constraint, because the second rule is more specific.

Comment: Think of it like this, since there are no constraints your first route is `*/*/*` and your second route is `project/*/*` which one is more specific? The second one is, so list it first to ensure it matches before things fall to the default route.

Comment: I think you are being confused because you may think that `action` and `controller` implicitly apply constraints to the routing, but they don't, they are just normal string variables.

Comment: It was exactly what was confusing me.
I thought, because there is no action, would go to the next route, but not quite how it works.  Thanks for the reply!